# How to use # and {enter} simultaneously inside a hotstring?

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to do this using Autohotkey:

Keyboard press

```
 ``#
```

to get two lines of text in my text editor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding: utf-8
```

I find it hard to achieve, because `#` and `{enter}` seems to be mutual exclusive in hotstring content.

For example (A),

``````
:*:`````#::/usr/bin/env python3{enter}coding: utf-8
``````

gives me:

```
/usr/bin/env python3
coding: utf-8
```

-- looks normal so far.

But if I write (B):

``````
:*:`````#::#!/usr/bin/env python3{enter}#coding: utf-8
``````

The added `#`s will trigger windows <kbd>Win</kbd> Key. I will not get `#` in my text editor.

How to workaround this? Thank you in advance.

Autohotkey 1.1.24.05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**#**" doesn`t need to be escaped in a hotstring definition.

```
:*:``#::`{#`}`{!`}/usr/bin/env python3{enter}`{#`}coding: utf-8
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#remarks

or

```
:*:``#::
Send {Raw}  
(
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding: utf-8
)
return
```

or

```
:*:``#::
Send {Blind}{Text} ; [v1.1.27+] 
(
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding: utf-8
)
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm